# Parse data in a new dataframe with correct headers taken from within the data

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a CSV that has been returned and the data is in a god awful state, I need to parse both the header and then the data out from each row.

This is an example of one row:

```
+--------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|           _c0|         _c1|                 _c2|           _c3|         _c4|          _c5|                 _c6|       _c7|           _c8|       _c9|      _c10|       _c11|         _c12|         _c13|      _c14|                _c15|         _c16|         _c17|         _c18|         _c19|         _c20|         _c21|         _c22|         _c23|         _c24|         _c25|         _c26|         _c27|         _c28|         _c29|         _c30|                _c31|         _c32|         _c33|         _c34|         _c35|         _c36|         _c37|         _c38|         _c39|         _c40|         _c41|         _c42|         _c43|         _c44|         _c45|         _c46|                _c47|         _c48|         _c49|         _c50|         _c51|         _c52|         _c53|         _c54|         _c55|         _c56|         _c57|         _c58|         _c59|         _c60|         _c61|         _c62|         _c63|         _c64|         _c65|         _c66|         _c67|         _c68|         _c69|         _c70|         _c71|         _c72|         _c73|         _c74|         _c75|         _c76|         _c77|         _c78|         _c79|         _c80|         _c81|         _c82|         _c83|         _c84|         _c85|         _c86|         _c87|         _c88|         _c89|         _c90|         _c91|         _c92|         _c93|         _c94|          _c95|          _c96|          _c97|          _c98|          _c99|         _c100|         _c101|         _c102|         _c103|         _c104|         _c105|         _c106|         _c107|         _c108|         _c109|         _c110|         _c111|         _c112|         _c113|         _c114|         _c115|         _c116|         _c117|         _c118|         _c119|         _c120|         _c121|         _c122|         _c123|         _c124|         _c125|         _c126|      _c127|      _c128|      _c129|      _c130|      _c131|      _c132|      _c133|      _c134|      _c135|      _c136|      _c137|      _c138|      _c139|      _c140|      _c141|      _c142|      _c143|               _c144|         _c145|     _c146|       _c147|     _c148|         _c149|          _c150|
+--------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|{"MANDT":"400"|"LEDNR":"00"|"OBJNR":"KS660000...|"GJAHR":"2022"|"WRTTP":"04"|"VERSN":"000"|"KSTAR":"0051040100"|"HRKFT":""|"VRGNG":"COIN"|"VBUND":""|"PARGB":""|"BEKNZ":"H"|"TWAER":"THB"|"PERBL":"016"|"MEINH":""|"WTG001":-1854554.89|"WTG002":0.00|"WTG003":0.00|"WTG004":0.00|"WTG005":0.00|"WTG006":0.00|"WTG007":0.00|"WTG008":0.00|"WTG009":0.00|"WTG010":0.00|"WTG011":0.00|"WTG012":0.00|"WTG013":0.00|"WTG014":0.00|"WTG015":0.00|"WTG016":0.00|"WOG001":-1854554.89|"WOG002":0.00|"WOG003":0.00|"WOG004":0.00|"WOG005":0.00|"WOG006":0.00|"WOG007":0.00|"WOG008":0.00|"WOG009":0.00|"WOG010":0.00|"WOG011":0.00|"WOG012":0.00|"WOG013":0.00|"WOG014":0.00|"WOG015":0.00|"WOG016":0.00|"WKG001":-1854554.89|"WKG002":0.00|"WKG003":0.00|"WKG004":0.00|"WKG005":0.00|"WKG006":0.00|"WKG007":0.00|"WKG008":0.00|"WKG009":0.00|"WKG010":0.00|"WKG011":0.00|"WKG012":0.00|"WKG013":0.00|"WKG014":0.00|"WKG015":0.00|"WKG016":0.00|"WKF001":0.00|"WKF002":0.00|"WKF003":0.00|"WKF004":0.00|"WKF005":0.00|"WKF006":0.00|"WKF007":0.00|"WKF008":0.00|"WKF009":0.00|"WKF010":0.00|"WKF011":0.00|"WKF012":0.00|"WKF013":0.00|"WKF014":0.00|"WKF015":0.00|"WKF016":0.00|"PAG001":0.00|"PAG002":0.00|"PAG003":0.00|"PAG004":0.00|"PAG005":0.00|"PAG006":0.00|"PAG007":0.00|"PAG008":0.00|"PAG009":0.00|"PAG010":0.00|"PAG011":0.00|"PAG012":0.00|"PAG013":0.00|"PAG014":0.00|"PAG015":0.00|"PAG016":0.00|"MEG001":0.000|"MEG002":0.000|"MEG003":0.000|"MEG004":0.000|"MEG005":0.000|"MEG006":0.000|"MEG007":0.000|"MEG008":0.000|"MEG009":0.000|"MEG010":0.000|"MEG011":0.000|"MEG012":0.000|"MEG013":0.000|"MEG014":0.000|"MEG015":0.000|"MEG016":0.000|"MEF001":0.000|"MEF002":0.000|"MEF003":0.000|"MEF004":0.000|"MEF005":0.000|"MEF006":0.000|"MEF007":0.000|"MEF008":0.000|"MEF009":0.000|"MEF010":0.000|"MEF011":0.000|"MEF012":0.000|"MEF013":0.000|"MEF014":0.000|"MEF015":0.000|"MEF016":0.000|"MUV001":""|"MUV002":""|"MUV003":""|"MUV004":""|"MUV005":""|"MUV006":""|"MUV007":""|"MUV008":""|"MUV009":""|"MUV010":""|"MUV011":""|"MUV012":""|"MUV013":""|"MUV014":""|"MUV015":""|"MUV016":""|"BELTP":"1"|"TIMESTMP":101246...|"BUKRS":"6611"|"FKBER":""|"SEGMENT":""|"GEBER":""|"GRANT_NBR":""|"BUDGET_PD":""}|
+--------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

The first part for example `MANDT` is the column header and the bit after the `:` is the value. I basically need to

A) Loop all the columns and change the headers so they relate to the bit prior to the `:`
B) then populate the rows with the second part after.

I've attempted a small piece of code just to edit all the columns like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

for colname in COSPDF.columns:    
    print(colname)
    COSPDF = COSPDF.withColumn(col(colname), lower(colname))
```

and I receive an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I've then done the "lazy" thing and found some code like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
split_df = COSPDF.select(split(COSPDF._c0, ':').alias('split_text'))
split_df.selectExpr("split_text[0] as left").show() # left of delim
split_df.selectExpr("split_text[1] as right").show() # right of delim
```

However this code only works one column that I have to "specify" which doesn't work when the CSV has 123 columns, I'm not doing it 123 times. Any assistance would really help with this please, it's had me stuck for hours.

**UPDATED**

Some rows from the original file:

```
"{""MANDT"":""400""","""LEDNR"":""00""","""OBJNR"":""KS66000011001070""","""GJAHR"":""2022""","""WRTTP"":""04""","""VERSN"":""000""","""KSTAR"":""0051040100""","""HRKFT"":""""","""VRGNG"":""COIN""","""VBUND"":""""","""PARGB"":""""","""BEKNZ"":""H""","""TWAER"":""THB""","""PERBL"":""016""","""MEINH"":""""","""WTG001"":-1854554.89","""WTG002"":0.00","""WTG003"":0.00","""WTG004"":0.00","""WTG005"":0.00","""WTG006"":0.00","""WTG007"":0.00","""WTG008"":0.00","""WTG009"":0.00","""WTG010"":0.00","""WTG011"":0.00","""WTG012"":0.00","""WTG013"":0.00","""WTG014"":0.00","""WTG015"":0.00","""WTG016"":0.00","""WOG001"":-1854554.89","""WOG002"":0.00","""WOG003"":0.00","""WOG004"":0.00","""WOG005"":0.00","""WOG006"":0.00","""WOG007"":0.00","""WOG008"":0.00","""WOG009"":0.00","""WOG010"":0.00","""WOG011"":0.00","""WOG012"":0.00","""WOG013"":0.00","""WOG014"":0.00","""WOG015"":0.00","""WOG016"":0.00","""WKG001"":-1854554.89","""WKG002"":0.00","""WKG003"":0.00","""WKG004"":0.00","""WKG005"":0.00","""WKG006"":0.00","""WKG007"":0.00","""WKG008"":0.00","""WKG009"":0.00","""WKG010"":0.00","""WKG011"":0.00","""WKG012"":0.00","""WKG013"":0.00","""WKG014"":0.00","""WKG015"":0.00","""WKG016"":0.00","""WKF001"":0.00","""WKF002"":0.00","""WKF003"":0.00","""WKF004"":0.00","""WKF005"":0.00","""WKF006"":0.00","""WKF007"":0.00","""WKF008"":0.00","""WKF009"":0.00","""WKF010"":0.00","""WKF011"":0.00","""WKF012"":0.00","""WKF013"":0.00","""WKF014"":0.00","""WKF015"":0.00","""WKF016"":0.00","""PAG001"":0.00","""PAG002"":0.00","""PAG003"":0.00","""PAG004"":0.00","""PAG005"":0.00","""PAG006"":0.00","""PAG007"":0.00","""PAG008"":0.00","""PAG009"":0.00","""PAG010"":0.00","""PAG011"":0.00","""PAG012"":0.00","""PAG013"":0.00","""PAG014"":0.00","""PAG015"":0.00","""PAG016"":0.00","""MEG001"":0.000","""MEG002"":0.000","""MEG003"":0.000","""MEG004"":0.000","""MEG005"":0.000","""MEG006"":0.000","""MEG007"":0.000","""MEG008"":0.000","""MEG009"":0.000","""MEG010"":0.000","""MEG011"":0.000","""MEG012"":0.000","""MEG013"":0.000","""MEG014"":0.000","""MEG015"":0.000","""MEG016"":0.000","""MEF001"":0.000","""MEF002"":0.000","""MEF003"":0.000","""MEF004"":0.000","""MEF005"":0.000","""MEF006"":0.000","""MEF007"":0.000","""MEF008"":0.000","""MEF009"":0.000","""MEF010"":0.000","""MEF011"":0.000","""MEF012"":0.000","""MEF013"":0.000","""MEF014"":0.000","""MEF015"":0.000","""MEF016"":0.000","""MUV001"":""""","""MUV002"":""""","""MUV003"":""""","""MUV004"":""""","""MUV005"":""""","""MUV006"":""""","""MUV007"":""""","""MUV008"":""""","""MUV009"":""""","""MUV010"":""""","""MUV011"":""""","""MUV012"":""""","""MUV013"":""""","""MUV014"":""""","""MUV015"":""""","""MUV016"":""""","""BELTP"":""1""","""TIMESTMP"":10124662650000.0","""BUKRS"":""6611""","""FKBER"":""""","""SEGMENT"":""""","""GEBER"":""""","""GRANT_NBR"":""""","""BUDGET_PD"":""""}"
"{""MANDT"":""400""","""LEDNR"":""00""","""OBJNR"":""KS66000011001070""","""GJAHR"":""2022""","""WRTTP"":""04""","""VERSN"":""000""","""KSTAR"":""0051040100""","""HRKFT"":""""","""VRGNG"":""COIN""","""VBUND"":""""","""PARGB"":""""","""BEKNZ"":""S""","""TWAER"":""THB""","""PERBL"":""016""","""MEINH"":""""","""WTG001"":7424891.07","""WTG002"":0.00","""WTG003"":0.00","""WTG004"":0.00","""WTG005"":0.00","""WTG006"":0.00","""WTG007"":0.00","""WTG008"":0.00","""WTG009"":0.00","""WTG010"":0.00","""WTG011"":0.00","""WTG012"":0.00","""WTG013"":0.00","""WTG014"":0.00","""WTG015"":0.00","""WTG016"":0.00","""WOG001"":7424891.07","""WOG002"":0.00","""WOG003"":0.00","""WOG004"":0.00","""WOG005"":0.00","""WOG006"":0.00","""WOG007"":0.00","""WOG008"":0.00","""WOG009"":0.00","""WOG010"":0.00","""WOG011"":0.00","""WOG012"":0.00","""WOG013"":0.00","""WOG014"":0.00","""WOG015"":0.00","""WOG016"":0.00","""WKG001"":7424891.07","""WKG002"":0.00","""WKG003"":0.00","""WKG004"":0.00","""WKG005"":0.00","""WKG006"":0.00","""WKG007"":0.00","""WKG008"":0.00","""WKG009"":0.00","""WKG010"":0.00","""WKG011"":0.00","""WKG012"":0.00","""WKG013"":0.00","""WKG014"":0.00","""WKG015"":0.00","""WKG016"":0.00","""WKF001"":0.00","""WKF002"":0.00","""WKF003"":0.00","""WKF004"":0.00","""WKF005"":0.00","""WKF006"":0.00","""WKF007"":0.00","""WKF008"":0.00","""WKF009"":0.00","""WKF010"":0.00","""WKF011"":0.00","""WKF012"":0.00","""WKF013"":0.00","""WKF014"":0.00","""WKF015"":0.00","""WKF016"":0.00","""PAG001"":0.00","""PAG002"":0.00","""PAG003"":0.00","""PAG004"":0.00","""PAG005"":0.00","""PAG006"":0.00","""PAG007"":0.00","""PAG008"":0.00","""PAG009"":0.00","""PAG010"":0.00","""PAG011"":0.00","""PAG012"":0.00","""PAG013"":0.00","""PAG014"":0.00","""PAG015"":0.00","""PAG016"":0.00","""MEG001"":0.000","""MEG002"":0.000","""MEG003"":0.000","""MEG004"":0.000","""MEG005"":0.000","""MEG006"":0.000","""MEG007"":0.000","""MEG008"":0.000","""MEG009"":0.000","""MEG010"":0.000","""MEG011"":0.000","""MEG012"":0.000","""MEG013"":0.000","""MEG014"":0.000","""MEG015"":0.000","""MEG016"":0.000","""MEF001"":0.000","""MEF002"":0.000","""MEF003"":0.000","""MEF004"":0.000","""MEF005"":0.000","""MEF006"":0.000","""MEF007"":0.000","""MEF008"":0.000","""MEF009"":0.000","""MEF010"":0.000","""MEF011"":0.000","""MEF012"":0.000","""MEF013"":0.000","""MEF014"":0.000","""MEF015"":0.000","""MEF016"":0.000","""MUV001"":""""","""MUV002"":""""","""MUV003"":""""","""MUV004"":""""","""MUV005"":""""","""MUV006"":""""","""MUV007"":""""","""MUV008"":""""","""MUV009"":""""","""MUV010"":""""","""MUV011"":""""","""MUV012"":""""","""MUV013"":""""","""MUV014"":""""","""MUV015"":""""","""MUV016"":""""","""BELTP"":""1""","""TIMESTMP"":10160936750000.0","""BUKRS"":""6611""","""FKBER"":""""","""SEGMENT"":""""","""GEBER"":""""","""GRANT_NBR"":""""","""BUDGET_PD"":""""}"
"{""MANDT"":""400""","""LEDNR"":""00""","""OBJNR"":""KS66000011001070""","""GJAHR"":""2022""","""WRTTP"":""04""","""VERSN"":""000""","""KSTAR"":""0051040105""","""HRKFT"":""""","""VRGNG"":""COIN""","""VBUND"":""""","""PARGB"":""""","""BEKNZ"":""H""","""TWAER"":""THB""","""PERBL"":""016""","""MEINH"":""""","""WTG001"":-509518.63","""WTG002"":0.00","""WTG003"":0.00","""WTG004"":0.00","""WTG005"":0.00","""WTG006"":0.00","""WTG007"":0.00","""WTG008"":0.00","""WTG009"":0.00","""WTG010"":0.00","""WTG011"":0.00","""WTG012"":0.00","""WTG013"":0.00","""WTG014"":0.00","""WTG015"":0.00","""WTG016"":0.00","""WOG001"":-509518.63","""WOG002"":0.00","""WOG003"":0.00","""WOG004"":0.00","""WOG005"":0.00","""WOG006"":0.00","""WOG007"":0.00","""WOG008"":0.00","""WOG009"":0.00","""WOG010"":0.00","""WOG011"":0.00","""WOG012"":0.00","""WOG013"":0.00","""WOG014"":0.00","""WOG015"":0.00","""WOG016"":0.00","""WKG001"":-509518.63","""WKG002"":0.00","""WKG003"":0.00","""WKG004"":0.00","""WKG005"":0.00","""WKG006"":0.00","""WKG007"":0.00","""WKG008"":0.00","""WKG009"":0.00","""WKG010"":0.00","""WKG011"":0.00","""WKG012"":0.00","""WKG013"":0.00","""WKG014"":0.00","""WKG015"":0.00","""WKG016"":0.00","""WKF001"":0.00","""WKF002"":0.00","""WKF003"":0.00","""WKF004"":0.00","""WKF005"":0.00","""WKF006"":0.00","""WKF007"":0.00","""WKF008"":0.00","""WKF009"":0.00","""WKF010"":0.00","""WKF011"":0.00","""WKF012"":0.00","""WKF013"":0.00","""WKF014"":0.00","""WKF015"":0.00","""WKF016"":0.00","""PAG001"":0.00","""PAG002"":0.00","""PAG003"":0.00","""PAG004"":0.00","""PAG005"":0.00","""PAG006"":0.00","""PAG007"":0.00","""PAG008"":0.00","""PAG009"":0.00","""PAG010"":0.00","""PAG011"":0.00","""PAG012"":0.00","""PAG013"":0.00","""PAG014"":0.00","""PAG015"":0.00","""PAG016"":0.00","""MEG001"":0.000","""MEG002"":0.000","""MEG003"":0.000","""MEG004"":0.000","""MEG005"":0.000","""MEG006"":0.000","""MEG007"":0.000","""MEG008"":0.000","""MEG009"":0.000","""MEG010"":0.000","""MEG011"":0.000","""MEG012"":0.000","""MEG013"":0.000","""MEG014"":0.000","""MEG015"":0.000","""MEG016"":0.000","""MEF001"":0.000","""MEF002"":0.000","""MEF003"":0.000","""MEF004"":0.000","""MEF005"":0.000","""MEF006"":0.000","""MEF007"":0.000","""MEF008"":0.000","""MEF009"":0.000","""MEF010"":0.000","""MEF011"":0.000","""MEF012"":0.000","""MEF013"":0.000","""MEF014"":0.000","""MEF015"":0.000","""MEF016"":0.000","""MUV001"":""""","""MUV002"":""""","""MUV003"":""""","""MUV004"":""""","""MUV005"":""""","""MUV006"":""""","""MUV007"":""""","""MUV008"":""""","""MUV009"":""""","""MUV010"":""""","""MUV011"":""""","""MUV012"":""""","""MUV013"":""""","""MUV014"":""""","""MUV015"":""""","""MUV016"":""""","""BELTP"":""1""","""TIMESTMP"":10124662700000.0","""BUKRS"":""6611""","""FKBER"":""""","""SEGMENT"":""""","""GEBER"":""""","""GRANT_NBR"":""""","""BUDGET_PD"":""""}"
```

Comment: what is the data type of the fields?

Comment: @samkart every column is a string as it is being read from a CSV.

Comment: looking at the data you pasted, it seems the data is actually a json data that was parsed incorrectly as csv. i'm noticing the curly brackets in `_c1` and `_c150` fields. just a thought, you could try to change the file's extension and load it as a json file.

Comment: @samkart Hi it does "look" like JSON it comes via a Connector for SAP, it actually doesn't form to JSON at all, literally each row is enclosed as such but if you try to format it like JSON it doesn't work.

Comment: interesting. but each row can be a separate json itself, and spark (i think) supports reading such a file. if possible, would be good to have a couple of rows from the raw file as well.

Comment: @samkart I have updated the question for you, they are the top 3 rows from the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247309/discussion-between-samkart-and-lynchie).

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You need to put Header name in Pandas Dataframe like...

df.columns = ["Column_Name1", "Column_Name2", "Column_Name3", "Column_Name4" and so on..]

And, If you want to use loop to append name for each col then you need iterate over the list and append based on the index and length of the list

Comment: @samkart String will datatype under a list

Comment: Ideally I don't to use pandas as it isn't optimised from my understanding and so the bigger the data gets, the less its able to handle it within Databricks.

Comment: Additionally writing out the columns names in free type is chaotic due to have nearly 150 odd columns to process.

Answer (score 0):

First read csv and get each key value pair by iterating over the columns

```
import pandas as pd
read_df = pd.read_csv(<your csv file path>)
dict_of_pairs = {pairs: read_df[pairs] for pairs in read_df}
```

Write it in another file

```
write_df = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in dict_of_pairs.items()}) // this will allow you to write even if some column has no values in it
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(write_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Somename for your sheet', index=False)
```

Hope this answers your question.....